# How can I produce a histogram of a color image?

Tags: c#, colors, histogram

How can I produce a histogram of a color image?

Comment: SO is not a "write this for me!" kind of site.  You need to narrow down your problem, show your work and include any errors you are receiving.

Comment: Use `Bitmap.GetPixel` and `{R,G,B}` values of `Color` to get you started...

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please edit your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: If you have Scilab, it is a great way to get the algorithmic part working and it has built-in graphics capability, then one can translate the algorithm to C# or some other language.

Answer (score 11):

This might give you a starting point:

```
    private void HistoGram()
    {
        // Get your image in a bitmap; this is how to get it from a picturebox
        Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) pictureBox1.Image;  
        // Store the histogram in a dictionary          
        Dictionary<Color, int> histo = new Dictionary<Color,int>();
        for (int x = 0; x < bm.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bm.Height; y++)
            {
                // Get pixel color 
                Color c = bm.GetPixel(x,y);
                // If it exists in our 'histogram' increment the corresponding value, or add new
                if (histo.ContainsKey(c))
                    histo[c] = histo[c] + 1;
                else
                    histo.Add(c, 1);
            }
        }
        // This outputs the histogram in an output window
        foreach (Color key in histo.Keys)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(key.ToString() + ": " + histo[key]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Almost verbatim what I was about to write. +1